# jQuery each function result how to do?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have to build a form and I have been working on the jQuery, but I get stuck in one step if you can give me any advice please,

So let me explain a bit about the form I have 20 products with offer1, offer2, and monthly fee all this till now is working perfectly i just need after you choose the amount of the specific product and when you press on the next button to display again the result but only where the amount was filled so basically only the products what the customer is interesting about them, and here is my main problem I know I have to do in jQuery each function but I am not sure how to do it ?

I have attached a picture to with the form so you can see an example
[form picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgane.jpg)

Edit:
Here is my code at the moment:

```
    function convert(value) {
        return "" + ((Number(value) || 0).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+ 
        (?!\d))/g, "$1,")) + "";
    }

    function testing(id, normaloffer, talesalesoffer, montlyoffer) {
        var normaoffertotal = normaloffer * $('#amount' + id).val();
        var talesalestotal = talesalesoffer * $('#amount' + id).val();
        var montlytotal = montlyoffer * $('#amount' + id).val();
        $(".normaloffertotal" + id).html(normaoffertotal);
        $(".telesalesoffertotal" + id).html(talesalestotal);
        $(".montlytotal" + id).html(montlytotal);
        $('#hnoffer' + id).val(normaoffertotal);
    }

    console.log(convert(10496.470000000001));

    function normaloffertotalcalc() {
        var sumnormaltotal = 0;
        $('span[id^="normaloffertotalspan"]').each(function () {
            var text = $(this).text();
            sumnormaltotal += parseFloat(text, 10);
        });
        $('#sumnormaltotal').html(sumnormaltotal);

        var sum_telesale = 0;
        $('span[id^="telesalesoffertotalspan"]').each(function () {
            var text = $(this).text();
            sum_telesale += parseFloat(text, 10);
        });
        $('#sumtelesaletotal').html(sum_telesale);

        var sum_montly = 0;
        $('span[id^="montlyofferspan"]').each(function () {
            var text = $(this).text();
            sum_montly += parseFloat(text, 10);
        });
        $('#summontlytotal').html(sum_montly);

        console.log('Normal Total Offer ' + convert(sum_normal));
        console.log('TeleSales Total Offer ' + convert(sum_telesale));
        console.log('Montly Total Offer ' + convert(sum_montly));
    }
</script>
```

and here is the html

```
<?php
    $count = 0;
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM products");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $count++;
?>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><?= $row[1] ?></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" placeholder="0" id="amount<?= $count ?>"
                                              name="amount<?= $count ?>" onblur="normaloffertotalcalc()"
                                              onkeyup="testing(<?= $count ?>, <?= $row[2] ?>, <?= $row[3] ?>, <?= $row[4] ?>)"
                                              style="-webkit-appearance: none; background: none; text-align: center; border: none; width: 40px;">
     </td>
     <td align="center">£<?= $row[2] ?></td>
     <td align="center">£<span class="normaloffertotal<?= $count ?>"
                                              id="normaloffertotalspan">0</span> <input type="hidden"
                                                                                        class="normaloffertotalspan"
                                                                                        id="hnoffer<?= $count ?>">
      </td>
      <td align="center">£<?= $row[3] ?></td>
      <td align="center">£<span class="telesalesoffertotal<?= $count ?>" id="telesalesoffertotalspan">0</span>
      </td>
      <td align="center">£<?= $row[4] ?></td>
      <td align="center">£<span class="montlytotal<?= $count ?>" id="montlyofferspan">0</span></td>
                </tr>
      <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: the form is fully working with jquery if i change the amount of the product from 0 to 1 or 2 whatever is calculate the column total price with the offer1, offer2 etc and a total sum of all the products. now i need to filter them in the next step with the products where i just change the amount from 0 to 1 or more

Comment: You should start by getting familiar with the Browsers builtin javascript debugger `F12` will normally load that

Comment: As with almost all questions on SO if you add some code for us to look at you will get a better response from the community

Comment: I am using the console for javascript debugger but is not a solution for what I need I don't have a problem with the code at this moment, I am just stuck on doing the next step

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution for me with this problem

```
            $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
            var val = parseInt($(this).val());

            if(val > 0){
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
            if(id){
                console.log(id);
            }
                console.log(val);

            }
        });
```

this is the code what I did and is working perfectly :)

Thanks to everyone who gives me advice

Ups one more thing, do you have any idea how can I export from MySQL only the products who have the id 2,7,1 example :)

Comment: Try not to ask further questions in answers.  If you have another question, post another question.